# Caching assets between builds in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-assets

I'm working on an Android project that has a large photo database stored in the assets directory (350MB of JPG files).

**The problem**: every time I run the application, it copies all 350MB, which takes several minutes. The files don't change between runs, so is it possible to copy them once and skip the assets directory on future runs? If so, how?

--

***Edit***: Regarding storing the images server-side: the project is for a client who hasn't approved a server-side component, so we're stuck with local storage for the time being.

Comment: Note: apps installed via the Google Play Store are limited to 50MB, so you'll have to use an [APK expansion file](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) if you want to release this on Google Play.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ah, I skimmed over an article about Google raising the file size limit to 4GB, but that actually included the expansion files. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play currently limits the file size of your APK to 50MB as per the [APK expansion file documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html). Per that same page, they suggest using an APK expansion file:

> Google Play hosts the expansion files for your application and serves them to the device at no cost to you. The expansion files are saved to the device's shared storage location (the SD card or USB-mountable partition; also known as the "external" storage) where your app can access them. On most devices, Google Play downloads the expansion file(s) at the same time it downloads the APK, so your application has everything it needs when the user opens it for the first time. In some cases, however, your application must download the files from Google Play when your application starts.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the `assets` folder is packaged into the final `apk` and uploaded to the device or emulator. This means that when you release this app, the installation will require a phone with 350 MB of available space. Not many devices have this.

You should consider alternate ways of delivering this content. For instance, you could upload to a web server and write your app to download only the needed images.

Comment: I agree in theory, but unfortunately the project is for a client who hasn't approved a server-side component. For now, it looks like we're stuck with local storage.

Comment: @Blake Another alternative is to use an [APK expansion file](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

Comment: Thanks! This seems promising.